# How to constrain a complex key depending on the parent to reside in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to design 5 tables with the following relations:

```
table1: id (PK)

table2: table1_id (FK table1), table3_id (FK table3)
table3: id (PK)

table4: id (PK), table1_id (FK table1)
table5: table4_id (FK table4), table3_id (FK table3)
```

How can I constrain table5's rows to respect the following condition:

```
(table1_id from table5's parent (table4), table3_id) must reside in table2
```

Comment: I do not believe `table5.table4.table1_id` is a valid syntax.

Comment: Normally this would tell me to change my design :) however, if you really want to do this, SQL has a CHECK constraint that can specify any kind of conditions (although most DBMSs put restrictions on what conditions you can actually specify), and most DBMSs support TRIGGERs (although the syntax varies by DBMS. Microsoft SQL server supports triggers (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Comment: @PM77-1 It isn't, it's just the best way I found to illustrate my issue.
The dot denotes going up to the parent.

Comment: Trigger would do it. I wonder if it can be enforced just through complex PK / complex FK combination.

Comment: "*Going up to parent*" is not clear as well. You have not mentioned any hierarchical structure.

Comment: @okaram Can you please show me how would you design the schema for the relations above?

Comment: @PM77-1 I specified the types for the keys, hope it's better.

Comment: Please spell out your logic for the first "key". It seems that you need to run a query just to get its value.  If this is the case, then you have to write a trigger for `table5` that fires on INSERT and UPDATE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63528/discussion-between-user2704-and-pm-77-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possibility with a user-defined function

```
CREATE TABLE t1(id int primary key);
CREATE TABLE t3(id int primary key);
CREATE TABLE t2(t1_id int references t1(id), t3_id int references t3(id));
CREATE TABLE t4(id int primary key, t1_id int references t1(id));


CREATE FUNCTION Foo(@t4_id int, @t3_id int) 
returns int 
as 
begin  return (select count(*) from t2 where t3_id=@t3_id and t1_id in (select t1_id from t4 where id=@t4_id)); end;
GO;

CREATE TABLE t5(
  t4_id int references t4(id),
  t3_id int references t3(id),
  PRIMARY KEY (t3_id,t4_id),
  CHECK ( Foo(t3_id,t4_id)>0 )
);
```